# get selected item in multiselect in vuejs component

Tags: vue.js, binding, multi-select

In my component, i have multiselect that should get options selected on matched value passed:

```
<select class="custom-select" multiple="" v-model="items">
          <option v-for="item in objects_list" :selected="itemSelected(item)" :key="item.id" :value="item.id">
              {{item.name}}
          </option>
        </select>
```

...

```
methods() {
  itemSelected(item) {
      let selected;
      let object_selected = this.value.filter(object => {
        console.log(object)
        if(item.id == object) {
          return true;
        }
      });
    }
```

the selected binding doesn't seems to work, how to correctly implement multiselect to bind selected options ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is to use the CREATED Function from Vue.js

```
<template>
  <div>
    <select class="ur-CSS-class" multiple v-model="selected">
      <option v-for="item in objects_list" :key="item.id" :value="item.id">
        {{ item.name }}
      </option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <span>Selected : {{ selected }}</span>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
var your_list = [
  { name: "one", id: 13 },
  { name: "two", id: 18 },
  { name: "three", id: 11 },
  { name: "four", id: 7 },
  { name: "five", id: 1 },
  { name: "six", id: 2 },
];

export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      objects_list: your_list,
      selected: []
    };
  },
  props:{
   inputData: {
       type: Object,
       required: true
    }
  },
  computed: {
      selected() {
        let selected = this.objects_list.filter(item => {
              return this.inputData.find(i => i == item.id);
           });
        return selected;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explains, but i want selected_options pre-computed in way that i have values getting from store

Comment: I would like to help you but could you be more specific?
From what I understood you have a list received by your store, then you receive this list objects_list and you want to display only the items whose item.id is equal to object (object that you calculate on your side). And so this display must be "instantaneous". Or you have a text field to add values in the list and they are displayed (below for example) only if they validate your condition ?

Comment: My goal is simply to have a list of items and pre-selected items from store in the multiselect field

Comment: I think I understood your problem, to solve it I used the CREATED() function, which allows you to sort (and in your case pre-select) the items you want.

Comment: Your solution works well, except you don't need to return object in created (), should be in computed or data logic

Comment: Oh yes sure, you see it. So if you, @user5329403, want, you can edit my answer (delete this return line) and I will accept it. And I think you will earn like 2 point.